# Gremlin Java : Get Vertices by max Edge count

Tags: java, neo4j, gremlin

Suppose we have a graph like this.

```
(User)-[:KNOWS]->(Friend)
```

I want to count all outgoing relationship from User and group them by user, then add some condition to filter. (Like more than 10 Knows)
This is what I did,

```
g.V().hasLabel("Friend").in("KNOWS").hasLabel("User").groupCount().next()
```

This is returning a map, so I can add the condition to filter the results. My question is , do we have any efficient alternative way to do this ?

Comment: Are you accepting Cypher solutions, or only wanting Gremlin?

Comment: @InverseFalcon only gremlin solution.

Comment: The web can correct me if I'm wrong, but Neo4j has no efficient way to do this. You would need to precalculate edge count per node (as edges added/removed, or periodically in batch) and save the value in the node index. At that point Neo4j can quickly look up all nodes that have value > threshold. Otherwise you must scan every Friend node in the graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if I understood your question correctly, but it sounds like you just want to filter all users based on their number of outgoing edges with the label `knows`.
In that case you can directly start at the `User` vertices and filter them based on the number of their `KNOWS` edges instead of doing a `groupCount`:

```
g.V().hasLabel('User').where(outE('KNOWS').count().is(gt(10)))
```

Until now I ignored any performance constrains. But as Paul Jackson mentioned in his comment it is not efficient to execute such a query in OLTP mode like this. Neo4j will probably iterate over all vertices, check whether they have the label `User` and then count their `KNOWS` edges.

You basically have two options to speed this up:

1. As Paul Jackson suggested: Add the edge count as a property to the vertices, pre-compute it and then index this property *or*
2. Use something like [Spark-Gremlin](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#_olap_hadoop_gremlin) if you really want to compute the edge count on the fly.

Comment: Yes, this is what I need. But I try this query with large graph and i'm getting OOM issues. Do you know how can we limit or skip the results to overcome OOM issue ?

Comment: See what Paul Jackson wrote in his comment to your question. I expanded my answer to discuss the performance problem with such a query.